# send Data to two or More Views From one Action Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an MVC4 application in which i am getting data from a `Webservice`

I have a `HomeController`  which has an `ActionResult` `Index()`

Consider the following code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id) {  
    // showing information about resource      
    Myproject.Data.ResourceData resourceData = new Myproject.Data.ResourceData();  
    var resource1 = resourceData.showResource(id);  
    return View(resource1);  
}
```

`ResourceData` class has attributes like `FirstName`, `LastName` and `public List<Project> Projects`.
In `resource1` i am getting datas like Personal Information and Project Information.

I have two tabs: *Personal Information* and *Project Information*. I want to split the data of `resource1` and wants to personal Information in **Personal Information  tab** and Private Information in **Private Information  tab**

Comment: Whats stopping you here, probably you are looking for some thing like jquery ui tabs.

Comment: I have hust read a tutorial about **Jquery** UI Tab... Can't it be done without **Jquery**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the data (model) in your view... you could use child partial views for each tab.
Then you just need to pass the model or part of the model to each PartialView.

**EDIT: Adding some code**

Your Index View is strongly typed and receives a `ResourceData` model. Then, in your Index View you can display 2 partial views to handle the 2 types of data this way:

```
<div class="PersonalTab">
     @Html.Partial("PersonalData", Model)
</div>

<div class="ProjectsTab">
     @Html.Partial("ProjectsData", Model)
</div>
```

"`PersonalData`" and "`ProjectsData`" are the names of the PartialViews you need to add in the same folder where `Index` is.

If you see, I just passed the entire Model object to each one... that will work... but you could do:

```
@Html.Partial("ProjectsData", Model.ListOfProjects)
```

So, in each partial you need to declare what is the type of Model:
`@model Myproject.Data.ResourceData`   (in case you pass the entire Model)

or

`@model IEnumerable<Project>` (in case you pass just the list of Projects)

**Note:** The code above just addresses a way to split a view in several partialviews. The logic of creating the Tabs is more of a javascript thing.

Comment: Hi, Thanks .. But can you give me some examples how to pass **model or part of the model to each PartialView.**

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in as simple by treating both as simple view. Separate the concerns (public, private with  elements in a single view and just use tabs from jquery, or even bootstrap is amazing. It will separate the concerns and will work much easier that you are thinking.

Comment: I have just read a tutorial about **Jquery** UI Tab... Can't it be done without **Jquery**?

Comment: yes it can be done without jquery too, using css only. Follow the link:  http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/twitter-bootstrap-101-tabs-and-pills/ , try basic tabs first.